# Stream Opus Audio over RTSP with FFmpeg on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, rtsp

I've managed to compile FFmpeg and libopus for iOS and am now trying to figure out how to open an RTSP stream via FFmpeg and then play that audio using either RemoteIO or AudioQueue or something.

The setup would be as follows:

1. Open an RTSP stream using an NSURL (rtsp://...)
2. I'm guessing have some sort of callback for the audio data
3. Feed it into RemoteIO or AudioQueue

I'm at quite a loss of how to go about doing this so the more in depth you can help here, the better. I haven't been able to figure out which part of FFmpeg I need, though I'm sure if I could wrestle the stream into some native type, I can figure out the RemoteIO/AudioQueue stuff.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: can you play the stream from CLI using RTSP client ( openrtsp, live555 )  ?   if you can get a verbose log of the protocol dialog using an open client, it may help you figure out what is happen when you attempt process on ios.

Comment: exampl: http://snipplr.com/view/63341/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only-p2/

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but it wasn't super helpful as iOS requires the API for ffmpeg, not the CLI. I managed to get it all working though!